Oracle Spatial Studio, No Datasource from Data Base
Some know why i cant see my DB connection when i try tyo create a dataset from de DB
enter image description here exmaple
find someone with the same issue, i try to resintall evereything where i deploying the war, eliminete sgtech dependencies, and intalling it again

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to click the from table/view option. This will then prompt you for the details on the table (or view) to use:

Select the data source (= the connection to a database) from the list of available data sources
Select the name of the table (or view) from the list of tables accessible in that datasource

